How to implement ion-modal events like `ionBreakpointDidChange` on controller modal
I have react code to call the modal using controller method like this:
const [showCommentsModal] = useIonModal(CommentsModal);

React.useEffect(
    function showCommentsModalOnCandleSelected() {
      if (!selectedCandleId) return;

      showCommentsModal({
        initialBreakpoint: 1,
        breakpoints: [0, 0.5, 1],
        onDidDismiss: () => {
          setSelectedCandleId(null);
        },
      });
    },
    [selectedCandleId, showCommentsModal],
  );

The problem is, how I can listen or implement the modal events that listed on this docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#events with my controller modal.

It should be used similar to the usage of didDismiss event.
